# handling result of async provider being called in another controller

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have the following provider:

```
globalLinksApp.factory('sectionStatus', function ($http: ng.IHttpService ) {
    return  {
            currentStatus: function (section) {
            let restBaseUrl = Url;
            $http
                .get(restBaseUrl, { withCredentials: true })
                .then(
                (response) => {
                    let apiResult = <ApiResult<[SP.News.SectionStatus]>>(response.data);
                    let status =  apiResult.data;
                    console.log("$scope.status called from factory = " + status.filter(a => a.section == section)[0].hidden);
                    return (status.filter(a => a.section == section)[0].hidden);                        
                },
                (errorResponse) => {
                    console.log('ERROR obtaining sections status: ' + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
                });
        }
    }
});
```

This then gets injected to following controller:

```
globalLinksApp.controller('GlobalFunctionsCtrl', ($scope, sectionStatus, $q: ng.IQService) => {
        $scope.webApplicationUrls = webApplicationUrls;
        let promotedLinkManager = new SP.PromotedLinks.PromotedLinkManager(SP.WebApplicationUrls.inside);
        let listGuid = '1234';

        $q.when(promotedLinkManager.getSchillingAppLinks(listGuid))
            .then((promotedLinks: [SP.PromotedLinks.PromotedLink]) => {
                $scope.promotedLinks = promotedLinks;
                                    $q.when(sectionStatus.currentStatus('GlobalFunctions')).then((a) => {
                    $scope.status = a;
                    console.log("scope status in the then block is: " + $scope.status);
                });
                console.log("$scope.status called from GlobalFunctionsCtrl = "+ $scope.status);
                $scope.isThisSectionHidden = ($scope.status == 'No');
                console.log("$scope.isThisSectionHidden = " + $scope.isThisSectionHidden);
            });

        $scope.srDone = () => {
            //code
        }
    });
```

console shows the logging message in this order:

```
$scope.status called from GlobalFunctionsCtrl = undefined
$scope.isThisSectionHidden = false
scope status in the then block is: undefined
$scope.status called from factory = No
```

I need to utilize the result provided from the provider API call, however it seems like the result does not get returned when I would like it to be, even after using `then`. What do I need to do to remedy this?

Comment: You have no `return $http`. It is *always* that simple.

Comment: d'oh! can you put that as an answer so I can accept it? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are very straightforward when it comes to chaining. If the result didn't appear in next `then` callback, or it seems that it didn't wait for previous promise to complete, this means that a promise wasn't returned from previous `then`.

It should be:

```
return $http.get(...)...
```